Torrent Announce URL Improperly Formatted?
I'm working on a BitTorrent client and seem to be unable to obtain information from the announce URL. I've included the generated URL below:
https://torrent.ubuntu.com/announce?info_hash=%2A%A4%F5%A7%E2%09%E5K2%80%3D6q%C4%C8%CA%AA%05&peer_id=-PC0001-000000000000&port=6881&uploaded=0&downloaded=0&left=6114656256&compact=1&event=started

The following was generated by parsing ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent which should be on Ubuntu's alternative download site.
I'm worried about how the info hash is encoded -- I checked it against the info hash displayed in another BitTorrent client (2aa4f5a7e209e54b32803d43670971c4c8caaa05).
Am I missing something? When I attempt to send the CURL request, I seem to get a valid response code and b-encoded response:
Response code :: 200
Tracker response: d14:failure reason63:Requested download is not authorized for use with this tracker.e


Looks like it is formatted correctly because the api returns a 200 but they also return an error in the body. Seems like you need to be a registered client with this tracker to download this file. I'm not sure where you would register the client.

I didn't include the download link to the torrent in my original post so I'm putting it here: https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads
